# How to switch UITableView and UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, uicollectionview

I have a project with a button that allows the user to switch between list view (`UITableView`) and grid view (`UICollectionView`) but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It's not very poor English but it is currently a poor question. What _exactly_ are you stuck on? What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: I am sorry@ but I am a newbie!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's suppose that your controller has a `UITableView` property named `tableView` and a `UICollectionView` property named `collectionView`.  In your `viewDidLoad` you need to add the starting view.  Let's suppose it's the table view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

Then in your button callback, swap the views out:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
     UIView *fromView, *toView;

     if (self.tableView.superview == self.view)
     {
         fromView = self.tableView;
         toView = self.collectionView;
     }
     else
     {
         fromView = self.collectionView;
         toView = self.tableView;
     }

     [fromView removeFromSuperview];

     toView.frame = self.view.bounds;
     [self.view addSubview:toView];
}
```

If you want a fancy animation, you can use `+[UIView transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:]` instead:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
     UIView *fromView, *toView;

     if (self.tableView.superview == self.view)
     {
         fromView = self.tableView;
         toView = self.collectionView;
     }
     else
     {
         fromView = self.collectionView;
         toView = self.tableView;
     }

     toView.frame = self.view.bounds;
     [UIView transitionFromView:fromView
                         toView:toView
                       duration:0.25
                        options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: thanks! But which ViewController can I use? TableViewController or CollectionViewController. How can I use TableViewDelegate and Datasource in a outsite class (not ViewController)?

Comment: Just use a normal UIViewController, and add both types of view to it as properties.  Or, if you want to keep the logic for the two views separate, you could create a UITableViewController and a UICollectionViewController and use their views instead of properties of the main controller.

Comment: In case your views are already part of the view hierarchy (e.g. by adding with xib/storyboard) you have to pass the `UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews` as one of the options parameter in `+transitionFromView:ToView:duration:options:completion:` method.

Comment: You should use ``UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight`` instead of ``UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight``.

Comment: This is brilliant thanks! But how would I get the subview's cells to call a method on the parent when selected? I want to push a controller on to the parent's navigation controller

Comment: Rather than having the cells call the method, you should make your controller be the views' delegates.  Then push the controller from within the delegate method.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to deal with it is having a single `UICollectionView` in which you can switch the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` implementation depending on the mode you want.

In order to convert from `UITableView` to `UICollectionView`, there are a lot of tutorials online, for example [this](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/converting-uitableview-uicollectionview.html).